# What is the need of collection framework in java?

Tags: java, collections

What is the need of Collection framework in Java since all the data operations(sorting/adding/deleting) are possible with Arrays and moreover array is suitable for memory consumption and performance is also better compared with Collections.

Can anyone point me a real time data oriented example which shows the difference in both(array/Collections) of these implementations.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- Arrays are not resizable.
- Java Collections Framework provides lots of different useful data types, such as linked lists (allows insertion anywhere in constant time), resizeable array lists (like `Vector` but cooler), red-black trees, hash-based maps (like `Hashtable` but cooler).
- Java Collections Framework provides abstractions, so you can refer to a list as a `List`, whether backed by an array list or a linked list; and you can refer to a map/dictionary as a `Map`, whether backed by a red-black tree or a hashtable.

In other words, Java Collections Framework allows you to use the right data structure, because one size does not fit all.

Comment: +1 Definitely a better answer. I deleted mine that was clumsy.

Comment: @Adeel: I could probably improve it even more (discussions of when to use which, Google Collections, etc.), if I weren't trying for Fastest Gun in the West. :-P

Comment: Arrays are not resizable, so is there any reason for them to exist since inception of ArrayList?

Comment: @Sreekanth Yes, `ArrayList` uses arrays behind the scenes and without arrays, `ArrayList` would not exist. Also, numerous language features use arrays directly (e.g., annotation parameters can be of an array type, but they cannot be `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 6):

Several reasons:

- Java's collection classes provides a higher level interface than arrays.
- Arrays have  a fixed size. Collections (see ArrayList) have a flexible size.
- Efficiently implementing a complicated data structures (e.g., hash tables) on top of raw arrays is a demanding task. The standard HashMap gives you that for free.
- There are different implementation you can choose from for the same set of services: ArrayList vs. LinkedList, HashMap vs. TreeMap, synchronized, etc.
- Finally, arrays allow covariance: setting an element of an array is not guaranteed to succeed due to typing errors that are detectable only at run time. Generics prevent this problem in arrays.

Take a look at this fragment that illustrates the covariance problem:

```
  String[] strings = new String[10];
  Object[] objects = strings;

  objects[0] = new Date();  // <- ArrayStoreException: java.util.Date
```

Comment: No, you won't be allowed to cast `objects` to `Integer[]`, because it's really of type `String[]`; you'll get `ClassCastException` at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Collection classes like Set, List, and Map implementations are closer to the "problem space."  They allow developers to complete work more quickly and turn in more readable/maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

For each class in the Collections API there's a different answer to your question. Here are a few examples.

LinkedList: If you remove an element from the middle of an array, you pay the cost of moving all of the elements to the right of the removed element. Not so with a linked list.

Set: If you try to implement a set with an array, adding an element or testing for an element's presence is O(N). With a HashSet, it's O(1).

Map: To implement a map using an array would give the same performance characteristics as your putative array implementation of a set.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your application's needs. There are so many types of collections, including:

- HashSet
- ArrayList
- HashMap
- TreeSet
- TreeMap
- LinkedList

So for example, if you need to store key/value pairs, you will have to write a lot of custom code if it will be based off an array - whereas the Hash* collections should just work out of the box. As always, pick the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Well the basic premise is "wrong" since Java included the Dictionary class since before interfaces existed in the language...

collections offer Lists which are somewhat similar to arrays, but they offer many more things that are not.  I'll assume you were just talking about List (and even Set) and leave Map out of it.

Yes, it is possible to get the same functionality as List and Set with an array, however there is a lot of work involved.  The whole point of a library is that users do not have to "roll their own" implementations of common things.

Once you have a single implementation that everyone uses it is easier to justify spending resources optimizing it as well.  That means when the standard collections are sped up or have their memory  footprint reduced that all applications using them get the improvements for free.

A single interface for each thing also simplifies every developers learning curve - there are not umpteen different ways of doing the same thing.

If you wanted to have an array that grows over time you would probably not put the growth code all over your classes, but would instead write a single utility method to do that.  Same for deletion and insertion etc...

Also, arrays are not well suited to insertion/deletion, especially when you expect that the .length member is supposed to reflect the actual number of contents, so you would spend a huge amount of time growing and shrinking the array.  Arrays are also not well suited for Sets as you would have to iterate over the entire array each time you wanted to do an insertion to check for duplicates.  That would kill any perceived efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not efficient always. What if you need something like `LinkedList`? Looks like you need to learn some data structure : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures

Answer (score 0):

Collection is the framework in Java and you know that framework is very easy to use rather than implementing and then use it and your concern is that why we don't use the array there are drawbacks of array like it is static you have to define the size of row at least in beginning, so if your array is large then it would result primarily in wastage of large memory.
So you can prefer ArrayList over it which is inside the collection hierarchy.

Complexity is other issue like you want to insert in array then you have to trace it upto define index so over it you can use LinkedList all functions are implemented only you need to use and became your code less complex and you can read there are various advantages of collection hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**Java Collections** came up with different functionality,usability and convenience.

When in an application we want to work on group of Objects, Only ARRAY can not help us,Or rather they might leads to do things with some cumbersome operations.

One important difference, is one of usability and convenience, especially given that Collections automatically expand in size when needed:

Collections came up with methods to simplify our work.

**Each one has a unique feature:**

- **List-** Essentially a variable-size array;
  You can usually add/remove items at any arbitrary position;
  The order of the items is well defined (i.e. you can say what position a given item goes in in the list).

  **Used**- Most cases where you just need to store or iterate through a "bunch of things" and later iterate through them.
- **Set-** Things can be "there or not"— when you add items to a set, there's no notion of how many times the item was added, and usually no notion of ordering.

  **Used-** Remembering "which items you've already processed", e.g. when doing a web crawl;
   
  Making other yes-no decisions about an item, e.g. "is the item a word of English", "is the item in the database?" , "is the item in this category?" etc.

Here you find use of each [collection as per scenario:](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/how_to_choose.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Collection framework are **much higher level compared to Arrays** and provides important interfaces and classes that by using them we can manage groups of objects with a much sophisticated way with many **methods already given by the specific collection**.

For example:

- ArrayList - It's like a dynamic array i.e. we don't need to declare its size, it grows as we add elements to it and it shrinks as we remove elements from it, during the runtime of the program.
- LinkedList - It can be used to depict a Queue(FIFO) or even a Stack(LIFO).
- HashSet - It stores its element by a process called hashing. The order of elements in HashSet is not guaranteed.
- TreeSet - TreeSet is the best candidate when one needs to store a large number of sorted elements and their fast access.
- ArrayDeque - It can also be used to implement a first-in, first-out(FIFO) queue or a last-in, first-out(LIFO) queue.
- HashMap - HashMap stores the data in the form of key-value pairs, where key and value are objects.
- Treemap - TreeMap stores key-value pairs in a sorted ascending order and retrieval speed of an element out of a TreeMap is quite fast.

To learn more about Java collections, [check out this article](https://javatutorial.net/choose-the-right-java-collection).